# F# lazy recursion

Tags: recursion, f#, lazy-evaluation, tail-recursion

I am have some problems with recursion in Lazy Computations. I need calculation the square root by Newton Raphson method. I do not know how to apply a lazy evaluation. This is my code:

```
let next x z = ((x + z / x) / 2.);
let rec iterate f x = 
    List.Cons(x, (iterate f (f x)));

let rec within eps list =
    let a = float (List.head list);
    let b = float (List.head (List.tail list));
    let rest = (List.tail (List.tail (list)));
    if (abs(a - b) <= eps * abs(b))
        then b
        else within eps (List.tail (list));
let lazySqrt a0 eps z = 
    within eps (iterate (next z) a0);

let result2 = lazySqrt 10. Eps fvalue;
printfn "lazy approach";
printfn "result: %f" result2;
```

Of course, stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need **lazy** computations, then you have to use appropriate tools. `List` is not lazy, it is computed to the end. Your `iterate` function never ends, so the entire code stack overflows in this function.

You may use `Seq` here.
**Note**: `Seq.skip` almost inevitably leads you to an **O(N^2)** complexity.

```
let next N x = ((x + N / x) / 2.);
let rec iterate f x = seq {
    yield x
    yield! iterate f (f x)
}

let rec within eps list =
    let a = Seq.head list
    let b = list |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.head
    if (abs(a - b) <= eps * abs(b))
        then b
        else list |> Seq.skip 1 |> within eps
let lazySqrt a0 eps z = 
    within eps (iterate (next z) a0);

let result2 = lazySqrt 10. 0.0001 42.;
printfn "lazy approach";
printfn "result: %f" result2;
// 6.4807406986501
```

---

Yet another approach is to use `LazyList` from [F# PowerPack](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/tree/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack). The code is available in [this article](http://fpish.net/topic/Some/4/59403). Copying it to my answer for sake of integrity:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.LazyList 

let next N (x:float) = (x + N/x) / 2.0

let rec repeat f a = 
    LazyList.consDelayed a (fun() -> repeat f (f a))

let rec within (eps : float)  = function
    | LazyList.Cons(a, LazyList.Cons(b, rest)) when (abs (a - b)) <= eps -> b
    | x -> within eps (LazyList.tail x)

let newton_square a0 eps N = within eps (repeat (next N) a0)

printfn "%A" (newton_square 16.0 0.001 16.0)
```

Some minor notes:

- Your `next` function is wrong;
- The meaning of `eps` is *relative accuracy* while in most academic books I've seen an *absolute accuracy*. The difference between the two is whether or not it's measured against `b`, here: `<= eps * abs(b)`. The code from FPish treats `eps` as an *absolute accuracy*.

Answer (score 3):

You're using F# lists which has eager evaluation. In your example, you need lazy evaluation and decomposing lists, so [F# PowerPack's LazyList](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/blob/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack/LazyList.fsi) is appropriate to use:

```
let next z x = (x + z / x) / 2.

let rec iterate f x = 
    LazyList.consDelayed x (fun () -> iterate f (f x))

let rec within eps list =
    match list with
    | LazyList.Cons(a, LazyList.Cons(b, rest)) when abs(a - b) <= eps * abs(b) -> b
    | LazyList.Cons(a, res) -> within eps res
    | LazyList.Nil -> failwith "Unexpected pattern"

let lazySqrt a0 eps z = 
    within eps (iterate (next z) a0)

let result2 = lazySqrt 10. Eps fvalue
printfn "lazy approach"
printfn "result: %f" result2
```

Notice that I use pattern matching which is more idiomatic than `head` and `tail`.

If you don't mind a slightly different approach, [Seq.unfold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340363.aspx) is natural here:

```
let next z x = (x + z / x) / 2.

let lazySqrt a0 eps z =
    a0
    |> Seq.unfold (fun a -> 
            let b = next z a
            if abs(a - b) <= eps * abs(b) then None else Some(a, b))
    |> Seq.fold (fun _ x -> x) a0
```